# Reduce number of remote objects

Tags: .net, apache-flex, remoteobject

I am making a flex application with .NET at back end (connection using WebORB and remote objects). I have five drop-down boxes in Flex component, each having unique values from different tables (e.g. city name, county name, user name, etc.). On page load (or can say creation create) I need to display these values so that users can select from the list. I was trying to get data using five remote objects (one for each drop down box.). I am wondering if there is way to get all data in one remote call.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it depends on your architecture, though.

Create a Proxy Service in .NET that calls each one of the respective services to get the controlled vocabulary that populates a drop down.  Then send back an array w/ five elements, one ofr each of your drop downs.

In most cases, I do not bother doing this.